# How to add a text with image with exactly half in the layout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a text in a linear layout android. Below that text I should keep two button exactly half with arrows at the end of the button. I am trying for this with various ways but I am not able to place the arrows correctly to both corners. Please help me in this regard.

[image]

My Code:

Below is my code. In that I am not able to view the arrows at right side. Please help me to keep the arrows exactly at the corners.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="120dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description"
            android:textColor="#101010"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#0096FF"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:id="@+id/text1" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text2"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#0096FF"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:id="@+id/text2" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `weights` in a `LinearLayour` in order to equally size `Views`.

For this to work, you will have to ensure that you add `android:layout_width="0dp"` (or `layout_height` if the LinearLayout is set to a vertical orientation) in order for the `weight` to take precedence.

For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Planting trees is good and useful because when a tree is planted, Chuck Norris round-house kicks himself in the face whilst dividing by Zero." />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The above XML produces the following:

[image]

In order to ensure that the arrows are at the exact corner, you must override the system `Button` in your `styles` xml and within there specify 0 padding for the relevant corner.

For example:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

To align the text within a `Button` or a `TextView` to the left, simply add `android:gravity="left|center_vertical"` within the `Button` or `TextView. Example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="lol"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: yes the solution which u gave is correct, but I have some text above the buttons, and the button text should match with the above text alignment. How can we achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by alignment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean above the two buttons I am displaying a text say "Planting trees is good and useful.....". Now the button text should start from below the letter P in planting

Comment: Please revise the change above.

Comment: hi thank you, but as per my requirement the button text should start exactly below the above text..in the example u gave the button text is button 1, so the button 1 should start from "b" in by zero

Comment: Hi I mean to say the button text is right now center aligned but I want the button text starting from left of the button

Comment: Inside the `Button`/`TextView` XML, add: `android:gravity="left"`.